# struct has different size in shared object than in binary calling shared object

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I am converting a large (ancient) program to a new OS and driver.  The program, and driver, are 32 bit running on a 64 bit OS.  I've been having some difficulty when trying to open the driver.

After some testing I've determined the program I'm converting thinks a certain struct is 19412 bytes, while the the driver believes the struct is 19416 bytes.  This in turn leads to overwriting the content of a pointer when the driver tries to zero the content of a struct passed to it, leading to the rest of my issues.

I'm trying to figure out why the driver and program disagree on struct size.

The driver Makefile looks like this (retyped by hand due to connectivity issues, so forgive typos):

```
cc -g  -m32 -c -fPIC -I../inc -D_UNIX -D_LINX -D_EEEI -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 ../lib/icelib.c
cc -g -pthread -m32 -shared -lm -o ../lib/libice.so icelib.o 
ar -rcs ../lib/libice.a icelib.o

cc -g -m32 -I../inc -D_UNIX -D_LINX -D_EEEI -lm -o ice ice.c ../lib/libice.so
```

The program running it is a little more complicated.  as the binary dynamically loads an SO which in turn makes calls to the libice.so driver, and the So is built using multiple objects and .a files.  The code that actually does the call to the driver is contained in the PICbrd.o file:

```
g++ -Dpthread -D_REENTRANT -DINC_TYPEDEFS -DLINUX -DICEPIC -D__FILENAME__=\"PIC6brd.cpp\" -c -g -DDEBUG -pg -m32 -Wall -D__linux__ -D__BUILD_VERS__='"3.1"' -D__BUILD_NUMBER__="'3.8"' -D__BUILD_TIME__''""' -D__cplusplus -Dcsp_SHARED -03 c/src/PIC6brd.cpp -o c/obj/PIC6brd.o
```

There are also a ton of -I includes in the above, that I'm not including only because it triples the size of the command.  the includes include pointing to the same lib used to build the icelib.so

Just for sanity testing I tried replacing CC with G++ in the icelib.so build script.  I got far more warnings, but it didn't change the size of the struct in the SO.

What could cause the two binaries to have different struct sizes?

edit: 
The struct in question is way to large to include here, and references a number of other structs internally.  while mostly it contains int_4 and int_1 it does include some floats and doubles who's size is dependent on architecture.  However I compiled the driver using the 64 bit build script and checked the size of the struct there and it's significantly larger (19782 I believe).  it seems that a problem with 32 bit to 64 bit conversion would lead to more then a 4 bit difference.  I also ran the 'file' command on all the binaries that seemed relevant and they all report as 32 bit.

Comment: How about the use of types in the structure that change size on 32-bit vs 64-bit or padding changes.  Without seeing the structure, that's the best guess you are going to get.

Comment: @RichardCritten I added an edit for you to question.  I thought the same thing, but I struggle mostly with explaining why there would be only a 4 bit difference in sizes, since 64 bit version should be much larger.

Comment: Note that sizeof() is in bytes not bits (actually I'm not sure that technically even 'bytes' is correct by the standard but rather whatever the smallest unit addressable by the CPU is), however on anything modern bytes is certainly that unit.

Comment: Have you looked for preprocessor directives modifying alignment & padding (like [#pragma pack](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) for gcc) ? Check all headers in both programs (such a directive in a header file will affect a structure defined in the file including it).

Comment: For such a large struct it's only off slightly.What are the datatypes used in it? Perhaps its the handling of an enum or bool? Or some alignment issue.